# How to include Nutch in Simple Java Application?

Tags: java, nutch

I have a simple browser "hello world" applet being called:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class CrawlCrowd extends java.applet.Applet 
{
    public void init() 
    {
        resize(150,25);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }

}
```

I want to include [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/), so that I can crawl urls on the fly in the applet. How do I go about including it and executing a simple crawl?

Comment: Flagged to close.  A good answer to this question is far too long, and you're basically asking us to do the whole project for you.  If there is a specific part of this process that is giving you problems, ask about that.

Comment: I just want to know how to IMPORT the file. Do I just put the folder in the same folder as my CrawlCrowd file and then use import? I havent touched java in 5 years....

Answer (score 0):

Write a webservice, which runs in your server. Call the webservice from client side with the url list. Write url's in seed file on your server side.

Use Apache commons-cli in web service to run a script file which starts nutch:

```
Executor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
exec.setWorkingDirectory(file);
CommandLine cl = new CommandLine("./runCommand.sh");

int exitvalue = exec.execute(cl);
if (exitvalue == 0)
    System.out.println("./runCommand.sh succeeded....");
```

Comment: The whole point of the way I want to do it is that each individual node on the network must be able to scrape and process by themselves.